# access variable by literal variable name (except with eval and likes)

Tags: javascript, eval

say I have a variable holding the name of another variable

`var foo='varname'`

I want to get the value of `varname`

If `varname` was global I could do `window[foo]`, but `varname` isn't global.

If this was a personal project I would do `eval(foo)` without looking back, but in a professional environment `eval` is always frowned upon, so I am trying to gather first all the available options and see if it can be avoided.

The only alternative I can think of is `Function('return '+ foo)()` but this feels very much like `eval`.

I think the answer is no, but is there any way to refer to a variable **that is not a property of an object** that is not global using square notation or similar "safe" methods?

Thank you

-- more context --

Variables are set in a main function. conditions to be evaluated are from a json file. In the main, after getting the json, conditions are evaluated. if conditions are met something happens. conditions are in a json format, like `{cond1:{varname:'somevalue'}}`. I would like to test for `varname==='somevalue'`

Comment: JavaScript (setting aside `eval()` and `new Function()`, which you've already done) just doesn't have a way of forming a reference to a variable. In C++ you can use the `&` unary operator to do that, but JavaScript has no equivalent.

Comment: @Amit Joki. Variables are set in a main function. conditions to be evaluated are from a json file. in the main, after getting the json, conditions are evaluated. if conditions are met something happens. conditions are in a json format, like `{cond1:{varname:'somevalue'}}`. I would like to test for `varname==='somevalue'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I think the answer is no, but is there any way to refer to a variable that is not global using square notation or similar "safe" methods?

You're right: The answer is no. Instead, use an object and a property:

```js
var vars = {
    foo: "bar"
};
var varname = "foo";
snippet.log(vars[varname]); // "bar"
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

If you want to throw in something *else* that's generally frowned upon, you can combine that with the `with` statement to get things that *look* like variables, but are in fact properties:

```js
var vars = {
    foo: "bar",
    baz: "buz"
    // ...and so on
};
var varname = "foo";
with (vars) {
    snippet.log(vars[varname]); // "bar"
    // Looks like a variable:
    foo = "updated";
    snippet.log(vars[varname]); // "updated"
}
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

I'm not *recommending* it, just trying to give you options. :-)

Comment: Wow, thx for the `snippet.log();`, never seen it before, never get involved in SO snippet much though

Comment: @A.Wolff: :-) It (that script link you see in the snippet) is my (hopefully temporary) answer to http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 This really should be something built into Snippets, but for now...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Thank you for your answer. However, as you may have gathered, I was looking for a way to do it that would not entail restructuring the way variables are set.

Comment: @vinz: Sadly then, no need to read past the first six words of the answer. :-) Although I did add a second option for you above.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. Thank you for adding a second option. Now I just need to combine it with a `try catch` and I am ready to go :). I'll accept your first seven words as the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Hey you can use an array to do that an simply

```
(function(){
    var foo="varname";
    var arr=[];
     function ls(){
        arr["varname"]="soy varname";

         console.log(arr[foo]);
    }

    ls();
})();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bbsw99g8/

Comment: That works because arrays are objects, but it has nothing to do with the fact it's an array. Just an object (`{}`) is all you need.

Comment: you mean `var arr={}`? :)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder. My comment was actually for Ernesto's answer, but when I hit "Add Comment" you had already answered and my comment got below yours :)

Comment: but i don't know why a negative point for that, yeah arrays are objets, so what?, does what he needs

Comment: @Ernesto. Thank you for trying to answer my question, appreciated. That being said, though it wasn't me to downvote, I agree that your solution only works because in JavaScript arrays are objects, and what you do there is to access property of objects, not keys of associative arrays like you would do in PHP. The downvote I guess is for any beginner at JavaScript **not** to pick up bad habits by potentially emulating what you propose there.